# media query not working as expected

Tags: css, media-queries

why does this code make both divs appear on a landscape-oriented iPad?

```
/* CSS */

div{
    display:none;   
}
@media screen and (min-width: 48em) {
  /* IPAD PORTRAIT */
  body {
      /* DARK BLUE */
   background-color:#006;
  }
    div{
    display:none;  
  }
    #ipad-portrait{
    display:block;  
  }
}


@media screen and (min-width: 64em) {
  /* IPAD LANDSCAPE */
  body{
      /*bright green*/
    background-color:#3f0;  
  }


  /* an attempt to hide all divs before displaying 
     the one that says iPad landscape */
  div{
    display:none;  
  }



  #ipad-landscape{
    display:block; 
  }
}



<!-- HTML -->
 <div id="ipad-landscape">
 ipad landscape
 </div>

  <div id="ipad-portrait">
 ipad portrait
 </div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm I didn't know you could use `em` as a form of measurement with a media query.  `em` is relative to the font-size - awesome..

Comment: @potench I lifted it from [this site](http://jordanyoung.com/) . Which is really excellently done -

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your min-widths overlap.  A device that is a minimum of 64em wide is also a minimum of 48em wide.  What you might be wanting is something like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 48em) and (max-width: 63.999em) {
/* stuff */
}
```

Comment: but then why, as the styles are applying in the cascade of moving down the sheet does my `@media screen and (min-width: 64em) { div{ display:none;} ...` not work? thanks!

Comment: Because `div` isn't specific enough to override `#ipad-portrait` from the first media query.  See more on css specificity:  http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/