# Media Query Specificity Image sizing issue at larger viewport using additive css method

Tags: sass, media-queries

I am starting mobile first and adding css as the viewport gets larger, but i've run into an issue with a certain image scaling issue and i can't seem to make sense of it.

I'm using Sass to begin with.

@media 320 i include all my styles for a certain block of content on the page of which I have an image within this block and here is the CSS for this media query:

```
    section.catalog-grid {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    .cat-dvdr {
        @include btm-brdr;
        padding: 20px 0;
    }

    h4.catalog-title {
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        color: $blue;
        top: 0;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }
    h6 {
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 1em;
        color: $pale-grey;
        padding: 0 10%;
        margin: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }
    img.cat-img {
        @include center;
    }
    img.rocket {
        width: 40%;
        margin-top: 30px;
    }
    img.wizard {
        width: 50%;
        margin-top: 10%;
        margin-bottom: 10%;
    }
    img.order {
        width: 60%;
        margin-top: 10%;
        margin-bottom: 10%;
    }
```

@media min-width 568px I actually wanted the image to be a smaller percentage scale and here's my Sass that i added to this media query:

```
img.rocket {
    width: 30%;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
img.wizard {
    width: 40%;
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
}
img.order {
    width: 50%;
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
}
```

My thinking behind this is that since i'm only adding styles that are changing as the viewport gets larger i don't have to add all of the Sass for this block (as i did at the 320px media query) but rather just add the rules that I want changed.

However what is happening is that the 320px media query image percentage size is overriding my 568px media query percentage image size when the viewport is at 568px and i'm not sure why.

Attached is a screenshot of what is going on in DevTools and i suspect that the reason that the 320px style is overriding the 568px style is due to more specificity since it notes all the parent elements of this particular image.

However i've attempted to remove the specificity from the 320px file so that the only rules that i want to be affected on the 320px file would be. In other words not include the entire block and its children but only the classes i want adjusted at this specific viewport size and that didn't work either.

Does this make sense?

Here is the screenshot:

[image: This is the screenshot of the image at 568px viewport size and notice that the 568px media query width is being overriden by the 320px media query width]

Comment: possible duplicate of [media query not working as expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12735236/media-query-not-working-as-expected)

Comment: Not a duplicate. The solution was much different.

Comment: @nwalton Did you read the comments on the answer?

Comment: @cimmanon I've read them now. It looks like the other item had an issue with css order, while this one has the order correct but a problem with specificity. They do have the same symptoms though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the 568px query, the image is targeted as:

```
img.rocket { ... }
```

In the 320px query, it's:

```
section.catalog-grid img.rocket { ... }
```

Since you have the additional specificity on the 320px rule, it will always override the less-specific rule no matter where it is located in the style sheet. You'll either need to match that specificity in your 568px rule, or reduce the specificity of the 320px rule.

In your sass, it looks like you have `image.rocket` contained inside the `section.catalog-grid` block:

```
section.catalog-grid {
    ...
    img.rocket { ... }
}
```

That creates the compiled rule you're seeing.